# Counterintuitive behaviour of linked CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=net-6.0) states that CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource method "creates a CancellationTokenSource that will be in the canceled state when any of the source tokens are in the canceled state."

However, the following code prints:

```
Cancellation. Token: Timeout
Timeout: True
Linked: False
Cancellation. Token: Linked
Timeout: True
Linked: True
```

I.e. the first time around, the linked token is *not* actually cancelled ( linked.Token.IsCancellationRequested == false, and ThrowIfCancellationRequested does not throw) while its source token is cancelled. But then, once passed to Task.Delay, it suddently wakes up and starts working as expected.

This happens in all versions of the .NET framework (tried with 4.8, Core 3, .NET 6), so it's apparently by design.

Is it documented somewhere?  What exactly needs to be done to linked CancellationTokenSource for it to pickup cancellation of the source token?

```
var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var linked = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeout.Token);
try
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), timeout.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException cex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation. Token: " + (cex.CancellationToken == timeout.Token ? "Timeout" : "Linked"));
}

linked.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
Console.WriteLine($"Timeout: {timeout.Token.IsCancellationRequested}");
Console.WriteLine($"Linked: {linked.Token.IsCancellationRequested}");

try
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), linked.Token);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException cex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation. Token: "+(cex.CancellationToken==timeout.Token?"Timeout":"Linked"));
}

Console.WriteLine($"Timeout: {timeout.Token.IsCancellationRequested}");
Console.WriteLine($"Linked: {linked.Token.IsCancellationRequested}");
```

Answer (score 3):

Linked cancellation tokens work via callbacks; they're not atomic. So, in this case, you have two callbacks on the source (timeout) token: the `Task.Delay` callback and the linked token callback. The order of the callbacks is not guaranteed.

Your code is observing that the `Task.Delay` callback is being invoked first, which is why you're seeing that the linked cancellation token isn't cancelled (yet). Once that callback completes, the next callback runs and cancels the linked cancellation token.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, adding even `await Task.Yield();` helps.

I'd still intuitively expect linked.IsCancellationToken to return true synchronously when timeout.Token.IsCancellationRequested==true though, as timeout.Token is passed to it. I.e. I'd expect the implementation to be not strictly callback-based but

`bool IsCancellationRequested => ...callback... || _linkedTokens.Any(x=>x.IsCancellationRequested);`

Comment: I agree that would be less surprising. Feel free to open an issue in the .NET runtime GitHub repository. It may be an oversight, or there may be some reason why that isn't feasible.